# Hide all console.log calls in WebStorm

Tags: debugging, webstorm, console.log

Is it possible to collapse / hide all strings containing just `console.log` calls?

Not remove them, but just temporarily hide, so they don't litter visible code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin, are be able to log/comment/delete all logs in the file 
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10986-console-log/